# how to perform image processing on windows phone

Tags: image-processing, windows-phone-7.1, libraries, aforge

kindly suggest an image processing library that work for windows phone. i was working on Aforge library but aforge is not compatible with windows phone .. so can any one suggest other library which is similar to aforge in working and perform hough transform in windows phone   thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I have recently ported all *AForge* libraries excluding the *Video* and *Robotics* libraries, but **including** the *Imaging* and related libraries, to portable class libraries, PCL. These portable class libraries currently target *Windows Phone version 8* and higher, *Windows Store apps* (Windows 8 and higher) and *.NET Framework 4.5* and higher.

You can find the PCL repository of *AForge* on Github, [here](https://github.com/cureos/aforge). I am also providing pre-compiled PCL libraries, you'll find these under the *Releases* tab, [here](https://github.com/cureos/aforge/releases).

Targeting *Windows Phone 7.1* is not realistically possible, since especially the *Imaging* libraries make heavy use of `unsafe` code. It is possible to employ `unsafe` code on *Windows Phone 8*, but not on *Windows Phone 7.1*.